# divide div into left and right without container div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

in my code div add dynamic and i don't want to use extra div like `<div class"left/right">` for contain left or right div.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 left">demo1</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 left">demo2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 right">demo3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

using this code my div look like

```
------------------
| demo1 |
------------------
| demo2 | demo3 |
------------------
```

but i want, for ex.

```
------------------
| demo1 | demo3 |
------------------
| demo2 | demo4 |
------------------
| demo5 |
```

mean right div set always right or left on left side.
if there is any solution in Bootstrap then its good for me.

Comment: You can use the following isotope jquery plugin:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: no thanks,I want this using html and css.

Comment: () `1, 3, 2, 4, 5` what logic is that?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i give just example. in my side div add dynamic,at that time div may add left continues 3 time and 4th div on right then sequence is `1,4,2,3`.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `.row` container as it is restricting the element to belong inside that container itself. I tried this using `float: left` and `float: right`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8 left">demo1</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 left">demo2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 right">demo3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 right">demo4</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 right">demo5</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 left">demo6</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 right">demo7</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 right">demo8</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}
.container > div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
.left + .left {
    clear: left;
}
.right + .right {
    clear: right;
}
.right + .right ~ .left, .left + .left ~ .right {
    position: relative;  /* or use just margin-top */
    top: -110px;      /* height + margin-top + margin-bottom */
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/cw4wupkg/1/)**

[Note]: If you have more elements of left/right in serial wise, then you should use like this:

```
.right + .right + .right ~ .left, .left + .left + .left ~ .right{
    position: relative;
    top: -220px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but in my live code there is require a `.row` container and there is not fix how many left or right div.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**
Using twitter bootstrap structure

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">demo1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">demo2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">demo3</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">demo4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">demo5</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">demo6</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Method 2**

Or you can simple try that

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="equaldivs">

            <div>demo1</div>
            <div>demo2</div>
            <div>demo3</div>
            <div>demo4</div>
            <div>demo5</div>
            <div>demo6</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and into your style.css

```
#equaldivs div:nth-child(odd) {
    width:50%;
    float:left
}
#equaldivs div:nth-child(even) {
    width:50%;
    float:right
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don’t want this type of method,because left div want always left and right on right.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

**HTML**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 left">demo1</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 left">demo2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 right">demo3</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 left">demo4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 right">demo5</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 right">demo6</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 left">demo7</div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row{width:100%}
.left{width:50%; float:left; min-height:20%; clear:left;}
.right{width:50%; float:right; margin-left:-50%; min-height:20%; clear:right}
```

Comment: no its not work, demo3 start after demo2. mean not parallel to demo1.
see this http://www.bootply.com/JeYSGpDbPx

Answer (score 0):

If you want without Container Then you can use below code.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="Col-md-6">
       <p>Left Side</p>
     </div>

     <div class="Col-md-6">
       <p>Right Side</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no i don’t want this type of code, container not want mean not extra container for left or right div. one is ok with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired view with a very little re-arrangement.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 left">demo1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 right">demo3</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 left">demo2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 right">demo4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See it in action [here](http://codepen.io/grvtiwari/pen/jchaL).